# TlbImp System.TypeLoadException: Int32[49285]' has too many dimensions

Tags: c#, dll, com, tlb, tlbimp

I have a C++-built tlb that uses `SAFEARRAY`; I used `tlb importer` to generate a DLL and build it with C#,I tried different options such as `/sysarray` and `/noclassmembers` to generate different signatures for a method:

```
public void GetList(ref Array HHNums, ref Array PersNums)
```

and

```
public void GetList(ref int[] HHNums, ref int[] PersNums)
```

In both cases I still get an error complaining with `System.TypeLoadException` that the array has too many dimensions defined. how do fix this error?

My CMD input is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\tlbimp.exe" /sysarray /out:ADI /noclassmembers /namespace:A.namespace myDTI.tlb`

Comment: You posted C# declarations.  Doesn't help us help you, we need to see the IDL you used to generate the C++ declaration.  If you don't have it then run OleView.exe from the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt and use File > View TypeLib to decompile myDTI.tlb

Comment: unfortunately OleViewer doesn't cannot view the type library because it fails to register a dll missing in ole viewer

Comment: @HansPassant this happens when i start the tool, , even without loading the dll

Comment: Dirty machine, that happens.  Click OK to move on and use the File menu.  Not being able to find the IDL is a fairly big problem, means you won't be able to fix this issue.  Do talk to the author of the C++ code to get ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this was the `ref` keyword based what I read online, [I converted the DLL into .il file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbc969t.aspx); I modified the code by removing the `[In]` from the parameters of the method:

```
instance void  GetListWithWeight([In][out] int32[]&  marshal( safearray int32) HHNums,
                                 [In][out] int32[]&  marshal( safearray int32) PerNums,
                                 [In][out] float32[]&  marshal( safearray float32) Wgts) runtime managed internalcall
```

and it became:

```
instance void  GetListWithWeight([out] int32[]&  marshal( safearray int32) HHNums,
                                 [out] int32[]&  marshal( safearray int32) PerNums,
                                 [out] float32[]&  marshal( safearray float32) Wgts) runtime managed internalcall
```

then I packaged the .il into a DLL and ran my program and then it worked fine. I hope this helps someone in the future